# How to install R package with its vignettes from source via RStudio `Install and Restart` button?

Tags: r, installation, build, rstudio, r-package

I've downloaded the source code of an R package (You may use [this](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown) R package by `git-clone`ing or downloading zipped version). I want to install the package via the `Install and Restart` button (4) in the `Build` tab (1). In configuration (2) I selected "Vignettes" (3).
Other configuration options I use:

[image]

Unfortunately, when I press `Install and Restart`, the package is installed but without its vignettes,i.e., no vignettes in the package's help page are displayed:
[image]

When I install the same package from CRAN, the vignettes are present:
[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to install a package with its vignettes by using this `Install and Restart` button. Maybe some configuration options are missing?

I use RStudio 1.3.1091, R 4.0.2 on Windows 10.

---

**Update:**

I'm aware of the solutions like:

```r
devtools::install_github("r-lib/pkgdown", build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

Or in the Terminal window:

```
R CMD build .
R CMD INSTALL pkgdown_1.6.1.9000.tar.gz
```

But my question is about the functionality of the `Install and Restart` button (or similar tools in RStudio).

Answer (score 1):

I installed this package in RStudio using `devtools::install_github("r-lib/pkgdown", build_vignettes = TRUE)`. The vignettes are installing using this method.

```
vignette(package = "pkgdown")
Vignettes in package ‘pkgdown’:

linking                       Auto-linking (source, html)
pkgdown                       Introduction to pkgdown (source, html)
metadata                      Metadata (source, html)
search                        Search (source, html)
```

Furthermore, `vignette("pkgdown")` brings up the main vignette for the package. However, the help documentation landing page for the package appears to have been updated to no longer link to the vignettes.

Report this as a potential issue: https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues

If the vignettes are not installing when using RStudio's menu- and GUI-based approach, perhaps the issue is a bug in RStudio and not in the package.

Comment: I'm aware of this and it is not the answer I'm searching for. To get the vignettes, you should install all the dependencies (including the suggested ones) and use `devtools::install_github("r-lib/pkgdown", build_vignettes = TRUE)`

Comment: I can get get the vignettes to install now, but it appears the help documentation file is updated. Also, I cannot reproduce your situation using the RStudio menus to install this package, so it may be an RStudio bug to report.

Comment: What OS do you use?